# Dimension of ASCII code

Tags: coding-theory

Let $C$ be the ASCII code. So,
$$C:=\{  (x_1,...,x_8) \in \Bbb{Z}_2^8: x_1+...+x_8=0   \} \subseteq  \Bbb{Z}_2 ^8 $$
and it's not difficult to show that it's a linear code.

I found on a book (without any further explanation) that this linear code has dimension $7$. So it is a $[8,7]$-code.

But how do we conclude that the dimension is $7$? Can we find a basis for this subspace?

Thank you.

Comment: If you see ASCII as $8$ bits but with $1$ used for parity checking, you get $8-1=7$.  Alternatively, there are $128=2^7$ elements of the ASCII code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the basis $$(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)\\(0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)\\(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0)\\(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0)\\(0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0)\\(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0)\\(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)\\$$is sufficient for describing $C$ and they are linearly independent (are calculations are mod 2).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why do we have linear independence?

Comment: @Chris : just write $\sum_{i=1}^7 \lambda_i e_i=0$, where the $e_i$ are the vectors given by Mostafa Ayaz : it will directly follow that $\lambda_i=0$, $\forall i$.

Comment: Thank you very much. And why this generates $C$?

Comment: @Chris: 1) the space, call it $V$, generated by these vectors is 7-dimensional because there are 7 linearly independent vectors. 2) all these basis vectors belong to $C$, so $V$ is a subset of $C$, so $C$ is at least 7-dimensional. 3) $C$ has dimension at most 7, because it is a proper subspace of the 8-dimensional space of all combinations of bits. Conclusion: $C$ is 7-dimensional, and $V$ must be all of $C$. Hence this generates $C$.

Comment: Or, if that was too much: "basic linear algebra relates the dimension of a solution space of a system of linear equations to the rank of the matris of coefficients of that system."